# pysaprk saveAsTextFile write multiple but the data is only all written in 1 single file

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have a test() function with returns a list of tuples and the final goal is to print in a file the content of the tuple called "test"

> [('something', 1),("test",['line1',
>   'line2','line3']),('somethingelse',3)]

```py
logs = sc.textFile("s3://my-bucket/file.txt")
rdd = logs.mapPartitions(lambda x: test()).reduceByKey(lambda a, b: a + b)).map(lambda (a, b): b if a == "test" else "").flatMap(lambda x: x)
rdd.collect()
```

> ['line1', 'line2', 'line3', 'line1', 'line2', 'line3']

I'm trying to write all the elements of this RDD on a file

```py
rdd.saveAsTextFile("s3://bucket/key/)
```

it works and sparks has created a multitude of parts file (215 files to be exact) but they are all empty except 1 of 1.2Gb which has all the data

```py
line1
line2
line3
line1
line2
line3
```

Is this normal behaviour? I thought that Spark would paralelize the writes and each worker would get a partition ? Why does the data gets written in only 1 file?

I have check with `rdd.getNumPartitions()` and it prints out 215.

Comment: Unless you show the code used to create `rdd` it is impossible to say if it is normal or not.

Comment: I have updated the question  with how the rdd is built

Comment: Have you tried repartiton(n) before saving the rdd.Can you check if the problem still persists after this.

Comment: Hi @KuldipPuriTejaswi. Yes by addition .repartition(100) it writes 100 parts files all filled.
Why do we need to add this??

Comment: In your map method you are returning a lot of empty values. That is why most of the partitions are returning empty files. Repartition shuffles and spreads the data evenly again.You can also use coalesce if you want to avoid shuffles.

Comment: I see. Is there a better way achieve what I'm currently doing? that map was the only way I found to select the tuple named "test"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is this normal behaviour?

Yes. It is normal behavior. You example data returns only one meaningful key - `"test"`. One you `reduceByKey` all the values for this key are shuffled to a single partition. The remaining values are just inconsequential.

The last two transformations

```
map(lambda (a, b): b if a == "test" else "").flatMap(lambda x: x)\
```

could be rewritten for clarity as:

```
filter(map(lambda (a, b): a == "test").values().flatMap(lambda x: x)
```

In other words your code keeps only values with `"test"` key and these are already on a single partition.

The part that really doesn't makes sense is grouping by key. You could as well

```
logs.mapPartitions(lambda x: test()).filter(map(lambda (a, b): a == "test")
```

which would keep data distributed as a side effect.

Comment: The thing is that I need to have the total results (hence reduceByKey) of each on my key.